# Is it normal for an Aloe vera to become spidery after blooming?

Tags: indoors, houseplants

My [Aloe vera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloe_vera) plant has bloomed.  It has gotten very "spidery", hanging out over the edges of the pot.  Some of the leaves down near the base have begun to dry up.  Someone told me they usually die after blooming.  Is there any truth in that? Is this spidery growth normal, can it be prevented or does it just happen in older Aloe vera plants?

Comment: A picture would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

It is Agaves that die after flowering, not Aloes. Aloe will continue to grow after the flower stalk blooms. You can cut the flower stem off or leave it to dry. If the plant is becoming leggy it may be because of low light. The plant does become spidery with age, but should also produce new growth centers at the base and from the main stem along its length. Dried leaves are normal and you can cut them back or leave them to dry and peal from the stem then if you like. I like to remove the brown leaves but they can be attractive in a garden. Aloes like plenty of water during growing season and dry soil when it is cold. Of course, they also will take all the sun you can give them.

Answer (score 1):

Aloe Vera plants need lots of sunlight and will continue to create new growth throughout its life. In order for this to happen the plant must focus more on its new growth than the older leaves and may be the reason why the outer leaves are dying. So take the old leaves and use them on your skin and eat it to get reap the historical benefits of the plant which is high in vitamins. At the same time though you must act quickly because once left dead for a day or two the plant begins to produce toxins and brown up. try to bury the old leaves so that the plant can take the nutrients and create more.

Comment: Note: Eating or suggesting to Eat Aloe Vera could be possibly dangerous as some species of Aloe plant are toxic. Please refer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloe_vera#Toxicity